# How do i properly use the replace function within my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to remove the \n for every line from the external file then I split the line into 2 lists. However the replacing function is not replacing anything while the code is running without errors.

```
infile = open('Kaartnummers.txt', 'r')
field1 = []
field2 = []
for items in infile:
    items.replace('\n', '')
    fields = items.split(", ")
    field1.append(fields[0])
    field2.append(fields[1])


print(field1, field2)


infile.close()
```

The external file has the following contents:

```
325255, Jan Jansen
334343, Erik Materus
235434, Ali Ahson
645345, Eva Versteeg
534545, Jan de Wilde
345355, Henk de Vries
```

Comment: You are replacing the string, then throwing away the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings in Python are immutable, so the `replace` method cannot work in place. It `return`s a new string, rather than changing the existing one. Try:

```
items = items.replace('\n', '') # save the return value from the replace call
```

Or perhaps you should use a method more specific to what you're trying to do (remove specific characters from the end of a string):

```
items = items.rstrip('\n') # or just .strip() if you don't mind removing other whitespace
```